# Как получить последнее значение двумерного списка C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите, как во view мне вывести последнее значение списка UpdateDateTime?

У меня есть модель:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Обновлен")]
    public IList<ProfileUpdate> ProfileUpdates { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Заметка")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Аккаунт")]
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
}

public class ProfileUpdate
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Выводил так:

```
@foreach (var pUpdate in item.ProfileUpdates)
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pUpdate.UpdateDateTime)
                    }
```

Comment: UpdateDateTime - не список, а поле класса. И что значит последнее? Последний апдейт последнего Customer? С сортировкой по какому то признаку? Если просто последнее, то `item.ProfileUpdates.Last().UpdateDateTime`

Comment: Последний апдейт Customer

Comment: Тогда попробуйте `item.ProfileUpdates.OrderBy(x=>x.UpdateDateTime).First()`

Comment: первый вариант подошёл, оформите пож-ста ответом, поставлю галочку, спасибо

Comment: Оформил. Рад, что помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае если ProfileUpdates уже сортированы, то вам подойдет

```
item.ProfileUpdates.Last().UpdateDateTime
```